# converting google map places autocomplete to responsive using bootstrap 3

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I keep trying to convert the below code, but I keep getting either no changes or it breaks the html.

This is the css

```
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      table {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      #map {
        width: 440px;
      }
      #listing {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 470px;
        overflow: auto;
        left: 442px;
        top: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      #findhotels {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 4px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      #locationField {
        position: absolute;
        width: 190px;
        height: 25px;
        left: 108px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      #controls {
        position: absolute;
        left: 300px;
        width: 140px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #country {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .placeIcon {
        width: 20px;
        height: 34px;
        margin: 4px;
      }
      .hotelIcon {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
      }
      #resultsTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 240px;
      }
      #rating {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
      }
      .iw_table_row {
        height: 18px;
      }
      .iw_attribute_name {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
      }
      .iw_table_icon {
        text-align: right;
      }
    </style>
```

Here is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Hotel Search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>

  <body>

    <div id="findhotels">
      Find hotels in:
    </div>

    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a city" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="controls">
      <select id="country">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="au">Australia</option>
        <option value="br">Brazil</option>
        <option value="ca">Canada</option>
        <option value="fr">France</option>
        <option value="de">Germany</option>
        <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
        <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="it">Italy</option>
        <option value="za">South Africa</option>
        <option value="es">Spain</option>
        <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
        <option value="us" selected>U.S.A.</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="map", class="col-lg-offset-2">

    <div id="listing">
      <table id="resultsTable">
        <tbody id="results"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div style="display: none">
      <div id="info-content">
        <table>
          <tr id="iw-url-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td id="iw-icon" class="iw_table_icon"></td>
            <td id="iw-url"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-address-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td>
            <td id="iw-address"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-phone-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Telephone:</td>
            <td id="iw-phone"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-rating-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Rating:</td>
            <td id="iw-rating"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-website-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Website:</td>
            <td id="iw-website"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried multiple ways to get this to be responsive and work with bootstrap 3.  I can get the map div to work, just not the controls at the top.

you can see what I have working at http://104.236.207.225/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your link and I see that the controls and map ***are*** responsive, but the map is not lining up with the controls because of the offset. The offset sets a margin that pushes the map element to the right. Don't use the offset.

Fix this line:

```
<div id="map", class="col-lg-offset-2">
```

Check the error by pasting your entire html here: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thank you I have removed the class information from the Div.  I did not realize it was already being responsive.

Comment: Anytime. I recommend you use Firefox as your browser so when you right click to "inspect elements" you can then click an icon that looks like a phone and it allows you to see what your website looks like on mobile devices like phones and tablets. I use it all the time.

Comment: I do that with chrome inspector, but did not bother to check before on this site.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize google finally added that function. Kinda cool how it shows popular devices to pick from. Thanks for mentioning that.